# Squared units on the axis, how to fix?

Tags: r

I want to show on my y-axis Leaf area index (m^2/m^2). However, on my plot, I can't see last bracket. I am just wondering what is wrong with the code?

`ylab=expression( "Leaf area index (m"^2/ "m"^2),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be with `bgroup`.

```
plot(1,1,ylab=expression("Leaf area index"~bgroup("(","m"^2/ "m"^2,")")))
```

[image]